# Bootstrap/JQuery mobile nav not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be experiencing issues with navbars using bootstrap and JQuery - on actual mobiles and in chrome's device simulation tool, the following navbar still shows up as a desktop navbar (no mobile toggle button, just appears as it would on any normal computer):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(Current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Apologies if it's something blindingly simple and thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Also, JQuery is being loaded before bootstrap js.

Comment: It's weird that it is not working... Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/aqf9d5q1/

Comment: Try removing aria-expanded and aria-controls properties.

Comment: works perfect, tested with latest bootstrap & jQuery...

Comment: Tried removing aria-expanded and aria-controls - no difference :/

Comment: It's not the code so there is something specific to your environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the most important `meta` value:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap documentation:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle **collapsed**" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
```

Your code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
```

You are missing .collapsed in your button.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I had taken this out earlier when trying to troubleshoot. Unfortunately it seems adding it back in has no effect.